I have the following error while designing a basic charge controller using PV array instead of Constant dc source
=== Simulation (Elapsed: 3 sec) ===
pulse =
1
Error:An error occurred while running the simulation and the simulation was terminated
Caused by:
Derivative of state '1' in block 'chargecontrol/PV Array/Diode Rsh/Transfer Fcn' at time 0.0 is not finite. The simulation will be stopped. There may be a singularity in the solution.  If not, try reducing the step size (either by reducing the fixed step size or by tightening the error tolerances)
I tried to change the tolerance sample time but it did not work and I tried a constant DC source and it is working. I have put the irradiation and temperature constant too.

Please show us some code so we might be able to at least guess what's wrong, otherwise you've got a fairly detailed error message there, you likely need to improve the initial conditions going into the transfer function block because its initial derivative is not finite. You might find it helpful to read about creating a [mcve], or read [ask]
